# Interface cannot be added to object literal

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I am trying to add an interface to an object literal in TypeScript  1.8.10, but it does not seem to work:

```
interface TestInterface {
    value: string 
}

let references = {
    interfaceReference: TestInterface
}
```

If I compile the code, the compiler throws the error `Cannot find name "TestInterface"` although it is correctly specified just before. I need to add the interface to an object as part of an Angular 2 project.

If I replace the interface with an abstract class everything seems to work:

```
abstract class TestInterface {
    value: string 
}

let references = {
    interfaceReference: TestInterface
}
```

However being able to use interfaces in these definitions would result in cleaner code. So, I hope there is a way to do this.

EDIT: To clarify what I want to do and why I am using interfaces:
Angular 2 includes a dependency injection mechanism. You can specify the mapping from abstract service definitions to concrete service implementations in an object literal in the bootstrap code:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [ { provide: TestInterface, useClass: TestClass} ]
```

However this does not work if TypeScript cannot set the value of an object property to an interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `tsc` complaining is, that `interfaces` don't get transpiled to JavaScript, but `classes` do.

So what you're doing in your code is assigning a JavaScript object to the variable `references`. The value after the `:` must be an expression with a value (a variable for instance), which works, if `TestInterface` is a class, because it gets transpiled as a variable like this:

```js
var TestInterface = (function () {
    function TestInterface() {
    }
    return TestInterface;
}());
```

To make your assignment actually work you have to rewrite it to something like this:

```js
let references: { interfaceReference: TestInterface } = { interfaceReference: null };
```

On the other hand, if you're keen about using interfaces, why start using JavaScript objects? A better way would be to encapsulate those references again like this:

```js
interface TestInterface {
    value: string 
}

class InterfaceReferences {
    constructor(public interfaceReference: TestInterface) {}
}

let references: InterfaceReferences = new InterfaceReferences(testInterface);
```

Comment: I am marking your answer as solution because it illustrates the "limitations" of TypeScript in my specific case. After further research Angular 2 is aware of the inability to set interfaces as object values and introduced OpaqueToken for this very reason

Answer (score 1):

This is the way how to define type:

```
interface TestInterface {
    value: string 
}

// firstly define type of the variable - next assign it value
let references: { 
    interfaceReference: TestInterface
} = {
    interfaceReference: null,
};
```

so, firstly - after the **`":"`** we define the type
and secondly - after the **`"="`** we define its value

even better would be to create an interface:

```
interface SomeType { 
    interfaceReference: TestInterface
}

let references: SomeType = {
    interfaceReference: null,
};
```

because we could reuse that `SomeType` later

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to set the value of `interfaceReference` to `TestInterface`, which doesn't exist in the runtime (as interfaces are not compiled down to JavaScript).

You should instead use a colon (`:`) to set the type of `references`, and then you can set your value.

```
interface TestInterface {
    value: string 
}

let references: {
    interfaceReference: TestInterface
};

references.interfaceReference = {
    value: "some value"
};
```